# How to properly generate an SSL key?

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to write a SSL server in Java

Here's my server

```
private final static String pathToStores = "C:\\Users\\Sky";
private final static String keyStoreFile = "server1.keystore";
private final static String passwd = "123456";

private final static int theServerPort = 8443;

private static boolean debug = false;

private void doServerSide() throws Exception {
    SSLServerSocketFactory sslssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslssf.createServerSocket(theServerPort);

    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
    InputStream sslIS = sslSocket.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslIS));

    String string = null;
    while ((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(string);
        System.out.flush();
    }
    sslSocket.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12"); // NOT SURE!!!

    String trustFilename = pathToStores + "\\" + keyStoreFile;

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", trustFilename);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", passwd);

    if (debug) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
    }

    new TLSServer().doServerSide();
}
```

I generate a key using this:
keytool -genkey -keystore server1.keystore -keyalg RSA
In my C:\Users\Sky

But I'm getting this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.throwException(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:160)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:173)
    at org.example.TLSServer.doServerSide(TLSServer.java:58)
    at org.example.TLSServer.main(TLSServer.java:85)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:113)
    at org.example.TLSServer.doServerSide(TLSServer.java:57)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:816)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2018)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.getKeyManagers(SSLContextImpl.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:864)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:1027)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
    at sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.<init>(ObjectIdentifier.java:257)
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getOID(DerInputStream.java:314)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Parameters.engineInit(PBES2Parameters.java:267)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(AlgorithmParameters.java:293)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:812)
    ... 17 more
```

I have asolutely no clue why this happens. The key was generated... I've been stuck with this for a few hours.

Besides this I got this client:

```
private final static String pathToStores = "C:\\Users\\Sky";
    //private final static String trustStoreFile = "keystore1,jks";
    private final static String trustStoreFile = "mytruststore.truststore";
    private final static String passwd = "123456";

    private static String theServerName = "localhost";
    private final static int theServerPort = 12345;

    private static boolean debug = false;

    private void doClientSide() throws Exception {
        SSLSocketFactory sslsf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslsf.createSocket(theServerName, theServerPort);

        OutputStream sslOS = sslSocket.getOutputStream();
        sslOS.write("Hello from TLS Client!\n".getBytes());
        sslOS.flush();
        sslSocket.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String trustFilename = pathToStores + "/" + trustStoreFile;

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustFilename);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", passwd);

        if (debug) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
        }

        new TLSClient().doClientSide();
    }
```

How do I generate a truststore?

The end goal should be to convert it to a TLS server. It shouldn't be too dificult if I solve this.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Sincerely.

Comment: _Exactly_ what version of Java's `keytool` did you use to create the keystore and what version to run the server? Some versions more than about 2 years old had bugs in the handling of PBES2Parameters and they varied over time. If you have or can get OpenSSL do `openssl pkcs12 -in keystorefile -info -noout` and see if it thinks the structure is okay. Or a cheap workaround is to use storetype JKS instead; although noninteroperable _and_ weak by design, this has never had implementation bugs :-?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 
It's actually very strange: when running the server I get an weird illegal option message
I tried to reinstall it but with no success :(